# Transparent view when switching from tabbar

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar

There is a `Tab bar` like instagram. There are five `tab bar item`. The third `tab bar item`, the one in the middle is "Add a new post". The problem is in the fact that any `item` of `tab bar`, when you tap on the "+" ("Add new post") open transparent view. On it will pop-up and vast. That is when we stamp on plus from any `item`, we always see that `item` where we were, but at the same time we have an active plus and a pop-up from a plus controller.

[Here's what I've tried.](https://gist.github.com/barbietunnie/e5547f35180436ac102cac52a15f8ca3) This is not an option.

On storyboard item "+" setting as follows:

```
Background = Clear Color
Drawing = Uncheck the Opaque checkbox
Presentation = Over Current Context
```

Without results.
Any Help on this

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have an modal segue from the tab bar to the view controller in your storyboard. Have you tried double checking that it's an embed segue, and not a modal presentation segue, that's linked to your + tab?

Comment: no, you suggest making a check, and if it's a tabbar + then making a modal transition?